# Different replace for the same word notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have these words: `TOP` and `LOCK`.  I have 49 times this word but I would like to replace it with a different word a lot of times. For example, the first time with `luc` and the second times with `pile`.

I would like to make it automatically.  I have the list of the replace words in a text file.  I use Notepad++.

I have searched on many sites, but cannot find a good solution.

Comment: Use replace? (ctrl +h)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have notepad ++ but can you highlight and right click there's an option to replace? or highlighting it then clicking format at the top and clicking replace and finally using Ctrl + F and replacing it that way? sorry if i could not help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
tap ctrl + F 
you can look at this pisture to get the picture:

http://im34.gulfup.com/Vkws5.jpg

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Highlight TOP
Press **Search** on top menu bar
Go to **Replace** 
Under **Find What**, in **Replace with** field type what you want to replace it with
Then hit **Replace All**

You will then see the changes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Notepad++ but I can do this with Sublime Text. I guess it doesn't hurt for you to try it out.

First, select all the words you want to replace with multiple cursor mode. Basically you can find `TOP|LOCK` with regular expressions, and hit Alt+Enter to convert the found words to multiple cursors.

Second, copy the words you want to replace and use the [Text Pastry](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Text%20Pastry) plugin to paste them in, one word at each cursor.

See here for a demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlFY0.jpg